# php code igniter Sweet alert with ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, sweetalert

Below is my ajax call code.

```
var date = new Date();
yr = date.getFullYear(),
    month = +date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) : date.getMonth() + 1,
    day = +date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
    newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
$("#dateupdated").val(newDate);
var url = "<?php echo base_url("resident/updateresident/{$resident->id }"); ?>"
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        swal("Operation completed successfully.");
        //  var objs = $.parseJSON(data);
        // var status=objs.status;
    }
});
```

It works fine but when I surround it with sweet alert confirm popup, it doesn't post data to controller. Can somebody tell me how to get rid of this?

The new code is:

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Are you sure that you want to cancel this order?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, cancel it!",
    confirmButtonColor: "#ec6c62"
}, function () {
    alert();
    var date = new Date();
    yr = date.getFullYear(),
        month = +date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) : date.getMonth() + 1,
        day = +date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
        newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    $("#dateupdated").val(newDate);
    var url = "<?php echo base_url("resident/updateresident/{$resident->id }"); ?>"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            swal("Operation completed successfully.");
            //  var objs = $.parseJSON(data);
            // var status=objs.status;           
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: format your code properly please

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution you are making mistake, here is the below code which will work for sure and it is tested.

```
 swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Are you sure that you want to cancel this order?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, cancel it!",
    confirmButtonColor: "#ec6c62"
}).then(function () {
   // Your codes goes here
});
```

here i have change `,function(){`  to  `.then(function () {` so it will work the code inside your function

and also i have change brackets after swal function you have just complete the `}` but you have to complete `})`